# Coordinates for Center of Screen for iPhone 6S

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, coordinates

I would like to position an object in the center of my `UIViewController`. I have tried to use `frame.width/2` and `frame.height/2`, for example, with a `UIView`:

```
let newView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2, width: 100, height: 100))
```

That method did not position the object in the center of the view as I expected. How can I position the object to the center of the view using the x-y coordinates of an iPhone 6s?

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual center coordinates of the window, I'd use:

```
let centerX = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxX / 2
let centerY = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.maxY / 2
```

But otherwise, in whichever ViewController you're working, the center of the view is a `CGPoint`, the position of which can be found with:

```
view.center
```

If you just want the `x` and `y` coordinates you can get them by just adding a `.x` or `.y` after `view.center`.